# CodeEval double square challenge

Tags: python-3.x

I am attemping [this challenge](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/33/), and I think I've solve it.  But when I put in the solution it always hovers between 60% to 70%.  What is wrong with my solution?

```
from sys import argv
with open(argv[1],'r') as test_cases:
    for item in test_cases:
        item = int(item)
        count = 0
        for i in range(int((item/2)**0.5)+1):
            if ((item - i**2)**0.5) % 1 == 0:
                count+=1
        print(count)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed on reading the first value **N** (number of test_cases)

```
with open(argv[1],'r') as test_cases:
    N = int(next(test_cases)) #get rid of it :)
    for item in test_cases:
        item = int(item)
        count = 0
        for i in range(int((item/2)**0.5)+1):
            if ((item - i**2)**0.5) % 1 == 0:
                count+=1
        print(count)
```